# Return to Start/Top in C # console application

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to go back to start in c# console program, and i am somehow able to do it, but the problem is that i am not able to do it using the Y/N statement. mean if i type the Y (yes) from keyboard then the program start from it's starting (beginning) point if i type N then it will terminate the program.

My Console code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace simple_calculation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool bktop = true;
            string option;
            while (bktop)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the values");
            int val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int val1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int res = val + val1;
            int red = val / val1;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the operator");
            string oper=Console.ReadLine();

                if (oper == "+")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("sum is:" + res);
                }
                else if (oper == "/")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("division is:" + red);
                }


            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("do you want to continue? enter Y/N");
                option = Console.ReadLine();
                    if(option=="Y")
                    {
                        bktop = false;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        bktop = true;
                    }
            }
                Console.ReadLine();
        }  
        }
    }
}
```

**What I want:** i want that when the program reaches to the else condition then there is a text appear in the console "do you want to continue? enter Y/N" if the user enter Y then the program start again and if the user enter N then the program will terminate.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking about. Maybe you should look through your code to see if conditions are correct. If you still can't figure out - make sure to provide [MCVE] (notice *minimal* part - dumping whole program is good start, but removing pieces that are not directly related to your problem will help one to provide good answer and not complain about random formatting for example)

Answer (score -2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // Change 1
        bool bktop = true;
        string option;
        while (bktop)
        {
            bktop = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the values");
            int val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int val1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int res = val + val1;
            int red = val / val1;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the operator");
            string oper = Console.ReadLine();

            if (oper == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("sum is:" + res);
            }
            else if (oper == "/")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("division is:" + red);
            }


            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("do you want to continue? enter Y/N");
                option = Console.ReadLine();
                // Change 2
                if (option.ToUpper() != "Y")
                {
                    bktop = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```